# html2pdf outputs duplicate content

Tags: html2pdf

When I feed html2pdf some html, for example:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>This is some content</p>
<hr>
```

I'm getting output like this:

## TitleTitle

This is some content

---

Yet when I echo this out normally to the browser, I see absolutely nothing wrong with the html markup.

Comment: Even I am getting the same error :(

Comment: Glad I am not alone in this. I know this doesn't solve the original problem, but I decided to use wkhtmltopdf instead. It is a binary that runs on the system but that seems faster than using php anyway. http://wkhtmltopdf.org/